# Python: call a function on access of any class attribute

Tags: python

This is a little hard to explain but here is what I want to do:  I want to create a function / property  on my class that will do the following. No matter what field I access it compares the value of that field to the rest of the attributes and returns something.

For example:

```
class myClass(object):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3

    def myProp(sef, accessed_attribute):
        return someting like you accessed <name of attrib>  and it is the largest value of all all of the attribues"
```

basically it compares the value to the rest of the attributes without having to write a property for each attribute.

Comment: I think you want `__getattr__`, but it's not clear what you're planning to do with it.

Comment: You can access all the attributes of a class or instance using `__dict__`; but wouldn't you be better using a dictionary or a subclass thereof?

Comment: Do you _really_ want class attributes here, not instance attributes?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get this function called when class attributes are accessed(not instance attributes), you can use a custom metaclass for your class and override `__getattribute__` method in this metaclass.